# Select Distinct between two tables inner join

Tags: mysql

I have table 1 which contains unique values and table 2 which contains multiple values for the same email.  What I want to do is select the first value of 'id' - table 2 contains a number of ids and matching emails

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
table1.email,
table2.id FROM
table1
INNER JOIN users ON table1.email = table2.Email
```

the problem is the output needs to be unique - i.e. one ID - the first one from table2 that is associated with a given email - currently we're getting multiple results - no unique or distinct values.

Comment: add sample data and expected output example from them

Comment: "...select the first value of 'id' ..." -- How do you define the first value of `id`? Remember that in relational tables rows do not have inherent ordering.

Comment: it does not matter, mysql simply returns multiple records and it seems to be sorted by the primary key, what I want to do is just have 1 ID - the ID does not need to be sorted - its a hash value - we just want 1 ID per email. thanks for the comment.

Comment: When you said _"multiple results"_ does it include _duplicates_ of same ID? If there are no duplicate id, were you expecting multiple results or just 1 row of result?

Comment: 1 row of result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably

1. any id - add `ORDER BY RAND()`
2. 1 row of result - add `LIMIT 1`.

So, the query might be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       table1.email,
       table2.id 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email 
 ORDER BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 1
```

Based on new information, it seems like you're looking for something like this instead:

**Note:** Works on MySQL v8+ and MariaDB 10.2+ that have *window function*:

```
SELECT email, id
 FROM
(SELECT table1.email,
        table2.id,
        ROW_NUMBER() 
             OVER 
           (PARTITION BY table1.email ORDER BY table2.id) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email) t
WHERE RowNumber=1;
```

1. Assign `ROW_NUMBER()` with `table1.email` as partition and sort by `table2.id` ascending (note that the default sorting of `ORDER BY` is ascending so there's no need to define it as `ORDER BY xxx ASC`).
2. Turn the base query into a subquery then do a `SELECT ..` with condition of `WHERE RowNumber=1`. Hence, it will return only a single row for each email.

Alternatively, depending on your data, you could just simply do something like this:

```
SELECT table1.email,
       MIN(table2.id) AS minID
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.email = table2.email
GROUP BY table1.email;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c47e871a8db8c95abf705dd2a8faec6)

Comment: order by could also be ID ASC - that will pick the lowest ID

Comment: limit 1 only gave us 1 record - we want 1 record PER unique email address not 1 record total....

Comment: Now, that's different. Please run `SELECT version()` to check MySQL version.

Comment: the MIN with the Group By combination worked flawlessly for what I needed. Thank you thank you!!!!